# $mdDialog autoWrap option not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, mddialog

I have the following function:

```
        scope.addNewAccountClicked = function () {
            return $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: modInfo.getModulePath() + 'add-account-dialog.tpl.html',
                autoWrap: false,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                controller: function DialogController(scope, $mdDialog) {
                    //controller stuff here
                }
            });
        }
```

The template it uses looks like this:

```
<tr-add-account-dialog></tr-add-account-dialog>
```

which is a custom directive that looks like this:

```
<md-dialog>
    <md-dialog-content>
        //Form to create new account
    </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

The problem is angular automatically wraps it in an md-dialog tag if it doesn't detect one at first, which results in it being wrapped in two md-dialog tags and it being broken.

This was apparently fixed [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4898) with the autoWrap option, but in my case it doesn't seem to do anything.

I am using angular version 1.4.7

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confused with the angular and angular material versions. $mdDialog is part of angular material, not angular, and my angular material version was 0.11 while the fix was implemented in 0.12